# QScrollArea not scaling to the window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use a `QScrollArea` in order to be able to put a lot of widgets on the same window. Unfortunately, the `QWidget` containing the `QScrollAea` (which is central) is not scaling to the size of the window, which makes it... not like I want... I tried different things but I can't fix it... any idea?

```
QWidget *central = new QWidget(this);
QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea(this);
QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(central);

this->setCentralWidget(central);
central->setLayout(vLayout);

//vect is not empty
for (elt t : vect)
{
    vLayout->addWidget(new TweetDisplay(elt, t));
}

//If I remove those three lines, everything is displayed but of course, I can't scroll.
scroll->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
scroll->setWidget(central);
scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

Picture for reference:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the central widget to `central` you should try using `scroll` as your central widget.  Thus, the proper line would be:

```
this->setCentralWidget(scroll);
```

Remember the scroll area uses `central` as the widget it contains already, so setting it as the central widget doesn't actually make sense.